# Accessing shares on the same Windows 10 computer that hosts a VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, smb

I have a Windows 10 Pro system setup a VPN host, just using the built-in Windows VPN service.  When I connect a client, the client can see other workstations on the VPN host's network, but not the VPN host system itself.  I can't even ping it.  I've disabled the Windows firewall on both ends and it still doesn't work.

I know I've done this before, but it was years ago I don't remember configurations I had to set.  How can access shares on the VPN host system from a VPN client system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually firewall issue.  What needed to happen:

Client: set VPN network profile to private

Server: create firewall inbound rule for ICMP (if you want ping), TCP 139 and TCP 445 on public networks (VPN on server can't be set to private, apparently)

Comment: Thank your for your sharing!